# How do you append a button/image to a page using a content script in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I want to overlay a button/image via content script so that it is available on specific URLs. I understand content scripts in principle, but I'm struggling with the combo of HTML/jQuery and content.

How do I get the image to show?

```
var div = document.createElement("div"); 
div.innerHtml = '<div id="qSidebarButton"><img src="imageURL.png" alt="Q Button" /></div>';
$("body").append(div);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as the correct property is `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`. Remember, JS is case sensitive.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div"); 
div.innerHTML = '<div id="qSidebarButton"><img src="imageURL.png" alt="Q Button" /></div>';
$("body").append(div);
```

That said, if you've included jQuery, then you can use that directly to append your HTML. It's simpler and more succinct:

```js
$("body").append('<div><div id="qSidebarButton"><img src="imageURL.png" alt="Q Button" /></div></div>');
```

Comment: Thank you...I tweaked the question to focus on the right edge question...not sure how to accept or not accept this solution since it doesn't match the edited question.

Comment: You've edited the question to now be something different to the original. That's against guidelines. Technically speaking it would be best to close this question (either delete or accept this answer, up to you) and to start a new one with the updated request.

Comment: Agree...the original had 2 questions, basically. I will edit it back to the question you answered, then accept. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem at all.